# Integration and natural log question

Tags: calculus, integration

WolframAlpha is confusing me. I'm working on two different integral problems, and with each one, for some reason, Wolfram switches the signs of the answer.

1. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+dx/(x^.5(x-1))
2. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(x-1)/(x^2-4)

For the first one, they get $\log[1 - \sqrt{x}] - \log[(1 + \sqrt{x})]$ (see under alternate forms, thats the one I'm using).

However, I get:
$\log[\sqrt{x}-1] - \log[(\sqrt{x}+1)]$ And so it differs by a sign, but its really bothering me, since I'm sure I'm doing it right. And the same applies to the second one:

They get:
$3/4 \log(-x-2)+1/4 \log(x-2)$

I get:
$3/4 \log(x+2)+1/4 \log(x-2)$

And so it differs by a sign again. (If this is a common mistake, then maybe you can point it out, but if this is just me and you can't see where I could have gone wrong, I can list my steps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The (real) indefinite integral is actually different in $(0, 1)$ and in $(1, \infty)$.  WolframAlpha gave you the answer in the first interval and your answer works for the second.  (Remember that in the real numbers, the logarithm of a non-positive number is undefined.)
2. This time WolframAlpha's answer is not defined for any real $x$.  Your answer works in $(2, \infty)$ but there is a different antiderivative in $(-2, 2)$ and yet another antiderivative in $(-\infty, -2)$.

This is a fairly subtle property of the logarithm.  Remember that any two antiderivatives of a function differ by a constant.  The problem in this case is that the constant is complex, so if you aren't working in the complex numbers you get genuinely different answers.

Comment: So my answer is correct then? I just wasted an hour trying to figure this out :(

Comment: That depends on which interval the question is asking you to find the antiderivative on.  (Possibly your teacher or textbook is not making this distinction.  That is unfortunate.)

Comment: I dont want to post another question for this, since it might be very similar, but can you explain why http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n+approaches+infinity+of+ln((n^2%2Bn-1)/(3n^2)) is equal to -log3? I get ln(1/3). (not sure how to fix the link in here, but make sure you copy that entire line because it cuts off)

Comment: -log 3 is equal to log (1/3).

Comment: @f-Prime:  the ^ breaks links and doesn't get escaped to %5E by the site.  If you change it manually, the link will work. (but it's too late for your comment)